# vuex state splice keep removing the last item

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I created a list on each list I've set up a remove method. Every-time I click the list in my jsfiddle I get what I want, but when I attach my project up with vuex it seems like the index is wrong. It just keeps removing the last item on my list no mater where i click. instead of the one i click.

```
    <md-table>
    <md-table-row v-for="(opt, index) in this.getAddedSegmentationList" :key="index">
        <md-table-cell>
            <ul >
                <li>Name: API_NEEDS_TO_BE_UPDATED</li>
                <li>Created: {{opt.created_time | newTime}}</li>
                <li>Finished: {{opt.end_time | newTime}}</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="channel-segements__tab-handlers">
                <li class="channel-segements__tab-handlers-items" @click="removeSegement(index, opt)">
                    <md-icon>delete</md-icon>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </md-table-cell>
    </md-table-row>
</md-table>


    methods: {

        removeSegement(index, opt) {

            this.getAddedSegmentationList.splice(index, 1)

        }
},


    computed: {
        getAddedSegmentationList() {
            return this.$store.state.channels.channelSegmentList
        }
},
```

My original jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ronoc4/eywraw8t/65812/ for testing to make sure it was possible.

Comment: Do items in `this.getAddedSegmentationList` have any ids? So you can use it here `:key="index"` insted of `index`? You can also try using `indexOf` to get the real index of the `opt`, something like this could work `this.getAddedSegmentationList.splice(this.getAddedSegmentationList.indexOf(opt), 1)`.

Comment: yes, I can give them id, which in turns. seems to work!

Comment: great it helps you!